# iOS 10 GMSMapView showing my location icon with white background

Tags: gmsmapview, ios10

This issue didn't show up in previous iOS versions. But in iOS 10 beta, the user location icon is displayed wrong. The blue dot is showing its frame in a different background instead of clearColor.

[image]

[image]

Is this an issue with iOS10? Any workaround to set the background color of the blue icon ?

I know we can put a custom icon by setting the blue dot to NO and:

```
 GMSMarker *pointMarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:currentPosition];
 pointMarker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage"];
 pointMarker.map = _map;
```

IS there any other way to set the background of user location to clear color ?

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happen in the Simulator, I've seen it on older iOS versions.

If this happens on the device then it's a bug.